# dotnet publish not iterating bundleconfig.json

Tags: .net, docker, bundler

Am trying to deploy AspBoilerPlate MVC project into a container.
So on dockerFile i has this lines :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["XxXxX.Web.Mvc/XxXxX.Web.Mvc.csproj", "src/XxXxX.Web.Mvc/"]
COPY ["XxXxX.Web.Core/XxXxX.Web.Core.csproj", "src/XxXxX.Web.Core/"]
COPY ["XxXxX.Application/XxXxX.Application.csproj", "src/XxXxX.Application/"]
COPY ["XxXxX.Core/XxXxX.Core.csproj", "src/XxXxX.Core/"]
COPY ["XxXxX.EntityFrameworkCore/XxXxX.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj", "src/XxXxX.EntityFrameworkCore/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/XxXxX.Web.Mvc/XxXxX.Web.Mvc.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/XxXxX.Web.Mvc"
RUN dotnet build "XxXxX.Web.Mvc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "XxXxX.Web.Mvc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "XxXxX.Web.Mvc.dll"]
```

So the issue while publish command, on dotnet build command am able to see output about iterating the bundleconfig.json as below :

```
  XxXxX.Web.Core -> /app/build/XxXxX.Web.Core.dll
  
  Bundler: Begin processing bundleconfig.json
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/_Bundles/account-layout.min.css
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/_Bundles/account-layout.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/_Bundles/shared-layout.min.css
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/_Bundles/shared-layout.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Tenants/Index.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Users/Index.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Users/ChangePassword.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Roles/Index.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Account/Login.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Account/Register.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Shared/Components/TenantChange/Default.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Shared/Components/TenantChange/_ChangeModal.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/_Bundles/datatables.ajax.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/_Bundles/helpers.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Feeds/FeedingActionTypes/Index.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Feeds/FeedingData/Index.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Feeds/FeedingActionCategories/Index.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Feeds/FeedingActionRoles/Index.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Feeds/FeedingContentAttributes/Index.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Feeds/FeedingContentAttributeTypes/Index.min.js
    Minified wwwroot/view-resources/Views/Notifications/Index.min.js
  Bundler: Done processing bundleconfig.json
```

But while executing the dotnet publish am getting this :

```
  XxXxX.Web.Core -> /app/build/XxXxX.Web.Core.dll
  
  Bundler: Begin processing bundleconfig.json   
  Bundler: Done processing bundleconfig.json
```

and the result of course running app without js and css, blank html elements

Any suggestion why publish command not producing the correct Minified files

Answer (score 1):

I found it, the issue was js libraries not pushed to Git. so either push all Libs content to Git or through dockerFile force `libman install`